# "Index was outside the bounds of the array" in c#. Why?

Tags: c#, arrays, exception, foreach

I keep getting an Exception in my for-each loop, and I don't understand why.

The error goes away when I make `array[i]` equal to `i`, but what if I want it equal to a different value?

Relevant code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] array1 = new int[5];

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                array1[i] = (i + 1);
            }


            foreach (int value in array1)
            {
                Console.Write(array1[value]);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: because you put 5 into array1[4] and then get it back out and try to access array1[5] with it. You can only index from 0..4

Comment: The `foreach` then using `array[value]` is incorrect. Using `foreach` over the `array1`, `value` will be each of the elements in the array.

Comment: Either replace the line `foreach...` with `for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)` again, or replace `Console.Write(array[value])` with `Console.Write(value)`

Answer (score 5):

The problem with your foreach loop is you are using VALUE as the array index, instead of simply printing the value.

Change your code to:

```
Console.Write(value);
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (**int** value in array1)
{
    Console.Write(**array1[value]**);
}
```

do this instead:

```
foreach (var value in array1)
{
    Console.Write(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are assigning `i+1` to array elment value and trying to access the array using this value.

```
        int[] array1 = new int[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            array1[i] = (i + 1);
        }
```

in above code

```
    array1[0]=1
    array1[1]=2
    array1[2]=3
    array1[3]=4
    array1[4]=5
```

value in   `array1[4]` is 5

now in foreach loop your are trying to access array at location 5 i.e `array1[5]` which throws index out of bound exception

Answer (score 0):

On this line, you are dimensioning the array with five elements, 0 to 4:

```
int[] array1 = new int[5]; // elements 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Then you are looping five times in your first "for" loop and setting every element equal to the index plus one: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.  In the next "for" loop, you are attempting to access the elements of the same array by their values, but when you reach the last element, whose value is 5, it fails because there is no index 5.  Remember, there are only indexes 0 to 4.

Comment: 0 to 4 which is 5 elements. I have a feeling you know this and made a silly mistake

Comment: @JoePhilllips -- of course :)